# Why my canoe automatically send a default message

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to send a message using my panel.
[image]
And I attached the CAPL file to the "HAP" node.The CAPL file is given in the following.

```
/*@!Encoding:936*/
includes
{

}

variables
{
  byte crc;
  byte data[64];
  message 0x329 msg1;
  msTimer mrrtimer100ms;

  message HAP_FD1 hap_fd1;
  

  
  //HAP_FD1
  int APS_BrkModSts = 0;
  int APS_ESP_BrkDistance = 0;
  float APS_ESP_Spdlimn= 0.0;
  int APS_ESP_TgtGearReq = 0;
  int APS_ReqCtrlEPS = 0;
  float APS_ReqEPSTgtAng= 0.0;
  int APS_WorkSts = 0;
    
  
}


on start
{
  setTimer(mrrtimer100ms,10);
}




on sysvar Local::APS_BrkModSts
{ 
}

on sysvar Local::APS_ESP_BrkDistance
{
}

on sysvar Local::APS_ESP_Spdlimn
{
}

on sysvar Local::APS_ESP_TgtGearReq
{
  
}

on sysvar Local::APS_ReqCtrlEPS
{
}

on sysvar Local::APS_ReqEPSTgtAng
{
}

on sysvar Local::APS_WorkSts
{
}


on timer mrrtimer100ms
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<64;i++){
    hap_fd1.byte(i)= 0x00;
  }
  hap_fd1.APS_BrkModSts.phys = sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_BrkModSts);
  hap_fd1.APS_WorkSts.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_WorkSts);
  hap_fd1.APS_ReqCtrlEPS.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ReqCtrlEPS);
  hap_fd1.APS_ReqEPSTgtAng.phys=sysGetVariableFloat(sysvar::Local::APS_ReqEPSTgtAng);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_TgtGearReq.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_TgtGearReq);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_SpdLimn.phys=sysGetVariableFloat(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_Spdlimn);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_BrkDistance.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_BrkDistance);
  
    //APA_control

  output(hap_fd1);
  
  
  setTimer(mrrtimer100ms,10);
}
```

[image]

When I start the project,I set "APS_ESP_BrkDistance" to 300. And I want canoe always send the signal as 300. But it seems that the canoe is sending a default message with both signal as 0.

[image]

I don't know the reason. If anyone can help me?

Comment: Most likely the interactive layer is configured to send the signal. The interactive layer does not know anything about your manual output of the message, so that interferes.

Answer (score 0):

there is a for loop for each byte in PDU HAP_FD1 that you initialize value = 0 in the on timer function.
this is the reason when timer is called, you see value 0, then 300.

```
on timer mrrtimer100ms
{
  int i;
  // for(i=0;i<64;i++){hap_fd1.byte(i)= 0x00;} 
  hap_fd1.APS_BrkModSts.phys = sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_BrkModSts);
  hap_fd1.APS_WorkSts.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_WorkSts);
  hap_fd1.APS_ReqCtrlEPS.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ReqCtrlEPS);
  hap_fd1.APS_ReqEPSTgtAng.phys=sysGetVariableFloat(sysvar::Local::APS_ReqEPSTgtAng);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_TgtGearReq.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_TgtGearReq);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_SpdLimn.phys=sysGetVariableFloat(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_Spdlimn);
  hap_fd1.APS_ESP_BrkDistance.phys=sysGetVariableInt(sysvar::Local::APS_ESP_BrkDistance);
  
    //APA_control

  output(hap_fd1);
  
  
  setTimer(mrrtimer100ms,10);
}
```

you can remove that line since the Panel Symbol Value can also set default Value as initialzation